# Is there a strip of land in China with unusual temperature properties?

Tags: weather

From this [source](http://politics.lilithezine.com/Interesting-Facts-China.html):

> In 1985 the Chinese press announced the discovery of a strip of land
>   1,000 metres by 15 metres, running down from a hill to a river, in
>   Huanre County, Liaoning province. In winter when the surrounding
>   temperature dips to -30° Celsius, the strip remains at 17° Celsius. In
>   summer the reverse occurs, and the strip freezes to a depth of 1
>   metre. The locals use the strip for growing vegetables in winter and
>   as a refrigerator in summer.

Does this land exist?

Comment: I assume by "Huanre County" they mean [Huanren Manchu Autonomous County](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huanren_Manchu_autonomous_county). Wikipedia's climate section for the county has no special mention of  an anomalous region.

Comment: A bit of searching let me to ["The People's Almanac Presents the Book of Lists/the '90s Edition"](http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0316920797) as the one of the original sources of this claim.

Comment: Even more search has lead me to find [this newspaper article](http://www.chron.com/CDA/archives/archive.mpl/1985_38715/unusual-temperatures-on-land-strip-studied.html) in the Houston Chronicle Archives that that indicates this was reported China Daily back in 1985.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd love to write an answer here where this frankly intriguing phenomena has been thouroughly investigated and tested to understand how the specific combination of climate, geology and topography has combined to form something which occurs nowhere else on Earth and seems to contradict conventional wisdom.

Unfortunately, I don't think we're going to quite get that!

This claim seems to have first surfaced in an [article](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/100-weird-years-1134528.html) in the [Independent Newspaper in the UK](http://www.independent.co.uk) written by Paul Sieveking, the editor of the [Fortean Times](http://www.forteantimes.com/):

> 47) In September 1985, the Chinese press reported a discovery on a strip of land, 1km by 15 metres, in Huanre county, Liaoning province. In winter, when the temperature drops to -30C, the strip remained at 17C; in summer, the strip froze to a depth of one metre. The locals used it as a fridge in summer and for growing vegetables in winter.

The first thing that makes me doubt that this is real is that searches for this phenomena turn up two blog posts repeating the infomation from the original independent article, without any further information, source or quote. Further searching reveals a [report in the Houston Chronicle](http://www.chron.com/CDA/archives/archive.mpl/1985_38715/unusual-temperatures-on-land-strip-studied.html) from 1985 apparenly reporting the finding in China - but yet again no reference back to the original report in China itself (Thanks @Rob_Z)

<strike>The second is that a look at the [administrative districts of Liaoning Province](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaoning#Administrative_divisions) show no area called Huanre (or similar). Similarly a Google Maps search for this name in China yields no results.</strike> (*Edit: This part of the mystery appears to have been solved. It looks like the area in question is [Huanren Manchu Autonomous County](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huanren_Manchu_autonomous_county)*)

Finally, Although quoted that the "Chinese press reported this in 1985" Im supposing that something so wildly fantastic would have been picked up by other news agencies around the world, however I can find no press information, Chinese or otherwise.

Comment: See my comment on the main question which I think resolves the missing county issue. You might like to give a bit more background about the kinds of articles the Fortean Times are known for, to put the veracity of this claim into perspective.

Comment: @Odd - Thanks, sorry for my shoddy proofreading. Also, I don't think that attacks on Fortean Times articles have any relevance to this question.

Comment: Plus, I don't actually think this has ever been reported in the Fortean Times - just written by an editor who happens to write for them.

Comment: @Oddthinking - I agree with Jamiec that attacks on Fortean Times aren't relevant, even more so since some of the articles they carry are quite skeptical as well. That said, Jamiec, I actually found a newspaper reference from 1985 that I linked in the comments on the question itself.

Comment: Sorry, my misreading. I thought it had been published in the Fortean Times. My goal wasn't to attack the paper (if the article had been in there) explain its level of journalism to people unfamiliar: e.g. an article in the Weekly World News or The Onion should be treated differently to an article in the Times.

Comment: @Oddthinking - Except, Fortean Times is not in the same league as Weekly World News or The Onion.

Comment: With regards to the administrative districts, [Huanren Manchu Autonomous County](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huanren_Manchu_autonomous_county) contains a town called [Huanren](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huanren_Town) so that might not be a strike against the claim as Huanren Manchu Autonomous County was organized in 1989 which is after the claim was published in 1985 so there might be some translation issues involved.

Comment: Answer updated. This is a wek answer, but save for the few I found and the one found by @RobZ there is precious little info online about this.

Comment: @Rob Z: But it is also a long way from the New York Times. I automatically don't trust any journalist, but Fortean Times reports tend to be a lot fringier, especially (I believe) going back a few years. In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortean_Times)'s words 'the "objective reality" of these reports is not as important.'

Comment: @Oddthinking - However, they aren't in the same boat either and make an attempt to present things as accurately as possible. I'd trust Fortean Times as third party source and for notable claims, but I wouldn't try to use them as a source to backup an answer unless it was one of their extremely well sourced articles that they have from time to time.

Comment: Erm, guys as  interesting as a convo is about the FT its both offtopic and unhelpful to the discussion of this answer. Please keep comments ontopic.